# Compilation of XAML files (WPF)

Tags: wpf, xaml

I would like to understand the compilation process of XAML files. Sorry for putting this question here but I really did not find any resource explaining this process in-depth.

I understand that XAML is compiled into a .baml file. But: Is the .baml compiled from the generated .g.cs file? Or is the .baml independent and is the IL code generated from the generated .g.cs AND the original .xaml.cs file - this would explain why MainWindow is partial. Which parts of the XAML declarations go into the BAML file? 
I would like to know also when the loading of a .baml file takes place (for example when talking about a window). 
Thanks for the help.

Comment: Title of the question is really not clear. It does not clearly states the purpose.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In my understanding based on the reference below, everything declared in XAML gets compiled to BAML; `.g.cs` and `.xaml.cs` files compiled to IL; `.xaml.cs` IL generated from codes in `.xaml.cs` file (obviously), and `g.cs` IL contains codes generated to interact with BAML (**instead of IL codes generated from BAML it self**).

Check this [blog post](http://vishalnayan.wordpress.com/2011/06/18/understanding-in-and-out-of-xaml-in-wpf/) for reference. To summarize, the author said that compilation of XAML happened in 2 steps :

> **Step 1**. The first step is to compile the XAML files into BAML using the xamlc.exe compiler. For example, if our project includes a file name Window1.xaml, the compiler will create a temporary file named Window1.baml and place it in the obj\Debug subfolder (in our project folder). At the same time, a partial class is created for our window, using the language of our choice. For example, if we’re using C#, the compiler will create a file named Window1.g.cs in the obj\Debug folder. The g stands for generated.
>
> The partial class includes three things:
>
> • Fields for all the controls in our window.
>
> • Code that loads the BAML from the assembly, thereby creating the tree of objects. This happens when the constructor calls Initialize Component ().
>
> • Code that assigns the appropriate control object to each field and connects all the event handlers. This happens in a method named Connect (), which the BAML parser calls every time it finds a named object.
>
> **Step 2**. When the XAML-to-BAML compilation stage is finished, Visual Studio uses the appropriate language compiler to compile our code and the generated partial class files. In the case of a C# application, it’s the csc.exe compiler that handles this task. The compiled code becomes a single assembly  Window1.exe) and the BAML for each window is embedded as a separate resource.

Comment: Can compile wpf xaml to xbf?

Comment: xamlc.exe is no more seperately available, now it is part of msbuild.