# Inspect xaml with Source Generator?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, sourcegenerators

I want to have some C# source code generated in response to xaml files. When looking at an `IIncrementalGenerator` it doesn't seem to be aware of xaml or able to look at them at all. I know that it gets combined into the dll/exe at some point so the compiler must be aware of the build artifacts at some stage.

Looking at what `IncrementalGeneratorInitializationContext` provides:

- `AdditionalTextsProvider` arbitrary files that are marked up as AdditionalText, but xaml files are under the "Page" Build action.
- `MetadataReferencesProvider` dlls involved in the build (system files and csProj dependencies) but this doesn't seem to have anything todo with xaml or any of the build artifacts that the xaml compiler outputs.
- `SyntaxProvider` and `CompilationProvider` seems to just be C# code that the compiler is trying to transform to a CLR representation.

Is there a way to use `xaml` (or if there is no option `baml`) data to inform my source generators?

Comment: _"When looking at an `IIncrementalGenerator` it doesn't seem to be aware of xaml or able to look at them at all"_ - of course, that's because Roslyn is for C#+VB.NET, whereas XAML is a completely different language [with its own compiler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21357330/compilation-of-xaml-files-wpf) - depending on your project your XAML files might be _transpiled_ to `.cs` files (usually found in your `obj\...` directory) - or directly to some other result or file-type (XAML is general-purpose and not specific to WPF/UI, y'see).

Comment: @Dai Yes but it's part of the csProj so I was hoping there was a way to look at the raw xaml text and perform search through it even if it's not directly being compiled by Roslyn as it's not something which is excluded in the csproj. Maybe the *.g.cs files (as those are actually compiled in) or the baml output that is made into part of the exe/dll